# SQL*Plus : Force it to return an error code

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, exit-code

I have a stored procedure that has an OUT parameter, indicating an error code.
If the error code is not 0, then I raise an error

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
 foo (err_code);

 IF (err_code <> 0) THEN
   raise_application_error(...);

END;
```

So far so good, but here's my question.

This piece of code (shown above) is executed by sqlplus, which is called from a shell script, which should exit with 0 / not 0 (as the sql script).

```
#shell script

sqlplus ... @myscript
return $?
```

When the raise_application_error executes, control goes back to sqlplus.

```
sql>
```

What I want, is a way of exiting back to the shell, without sqlplus returning a 0 on $?

Any thoughts? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm)

Comment: We do `whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode`, which passes a bit more information back to the caller of the script. We also do `whenever oserror exit 1` in case SQLPlus trips over on some sort of OS-level error.

Answer (score 0):

If you care which application error your PL/SQL raised, you can declare the return code as a SQL*Plus variable, and return have the PL/SQL procedure set it.

```
#shell script

sqlplus /nolog << EOF
connect uid/pw
variable retval number;
BEGIN
  foo (:retval);
END;
/

exit retval;
EOF

return $?
```