# Oracle JOB fails

Tags: oracle, bash, plsql, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a Oracle JOB that runs a executable (bash script)..
This scripts runs itself SQLPLUS which runs a PACKAGE

Check this

```
function run_pkg_load_svr() {
    if [ "$1" != "" ] && [ "$2" != "" ];
    then
        sqlplus -l -s $1/$2 <<EOF
            WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 99;
            WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 88;
            BEGIN
                PKG_LOAD_SVR.SP_MAIN();
             END;
            /  
EOF
        pkg_retcode=$?
        echo $DATE_LOG >> upload.log
        echo "PKG EXIT CODE: " $pkg_retcode >> upload.log
    fi
}
```

SO, if I run the JOB, its exit code (PKG) is 1

But, If I run manually the package or the script, it works

**STATUS is SUCCEEDED** in log events

How is possibile to have such a problem?

In addition, when **SP_MAIN** starts I populate also a log_table..
even that doesn't work

Comment: Maybe the oracle account that executes the script has different environment settings and can't run sqlplus for some reason. You need to capture more diagnostic information. btw why host out to a shell script that calls SQL*Plus which connects back to (presumably) the same database? It seems a bit overcomplicated, not to mention insecure as you are passing the password around as plain text.

Comment: Could you add the Oracle Job call you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably doesn't even connect to the database.

I get the same `1` status here if I give ***wrong user /password***:

```
host:/jcho $  sqlplus -l -s  a/b@database <<EOF
>  select 1 from dual;
> EOF
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus

host:/jcho $ echo $?
1
```

... First be [sure you are able to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840765/how-to-verify-sqlplus-cannot-connect).

## edit

I also get same error when database I try to connect doesn't exist:

```
host:/jcho $  sqlplus -l -s  a/b@unknown_database <<EOF
>  select 1 from dual;
> EOF
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
    
SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
host:/jcho $ echo $?
1
```

So make sure you're in the same context when commands are run from Oracle Job and manually. Especially, display content of environment variables `ORACLE_SID`, (`TWO_TASK`?), `ORACLE_HOME`  and `PATH` (`PATH` should contain `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`);

And also check variables are correctly set by displaying them from your script: add

```
 echo USER-PASSWORD: $1-$2
```

as first line of your function.

Comment: Hi, gonna check it

Comment: Well, when in my bash script I call the function 
run_pkg_load_svr $user $pass

edit: $user='dboracle'
        $pass='dboracle'

Comment: Then what happens when you do a `sqlplus -l -s dboracle/dboracle` from command line? do you get normal prompt?

Comment: Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters and Automatic Storage Management options

SQL>

I run without -l -s, anyway it works

I don't understand why If I run the script via command line, it works everything..instead via JOB ORACLE doesnt't

Comment: What do you get if you add `echo USER-PASSWORD: $1-$2` at the beginning of your script? Are the variables correctly set?

Comment: Done, now I'm passing the service name and it works, thank you